# Want to define around 20 variables using for loop

Tags: java, swing

i have a for loop which will run till the size of the arraylist,
I want to those many variables inside that loop,
can any please help me,
here is the sample

```
for(i=1;i<=filelist.size();i++) {
  ActionListener listener;
}
```

Note: variables should somehow be defined with different names

i have tried giving

```
ActionListener listener+i;
```

so that it defines variables as follows

```
listener1
listener2
listener3
listener4
..
```

but it is not working.
Any suggestion are also welcomed

Comment: Why not just use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)?

Comment: Ever heard of Arrays?

Comment: like! can you explain me a bit more

Comment: Are you trying to make dynamic variables?

Comment: Array,heard of that?see this..........

Comment: can you write the code for that

Comment: @user3755868: Probably not a helpful response but have a read through the link I posted. There's some sample code in it.

Comment: i want to define those many buttons as that of the size of the arraylist,

Comment: *"can you write the code for that"*  It does not matter if we can, since SO is not a code generation machine.

Comment: and if i use array,will it be possible to define those many action listeners along with the actionperformed methods

Comment: It's not a great question, but if @user3755868 doesn't know where to start searching for ways to solve the problem, piling on and being sarcastic won't help. Instead, pointing out the [how to](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking a good question would be better, as well as the section on [pasting a good example of your work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is the sort of thing that you need, and you declare it like this:

```
ActionListener[] listeners = new ActionListener[20];
```

and you access values in it like this:

```
listeners[0] = new ActionListener(); //Or whatever you need
```

or

```
listeners[0].methodCall();
```

The value in the `[]` is the number in the array that you'd like to access. So if you want the 1st, it's `listeners[0]`, the 2nd, `listeners[1]` and so on, up to `listeners[19]`, if the array is of size 20.

To fill the array with values, you can use a `for` loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    listeners[i] = new ActionListener();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap. It alows you to associate a name with a value.

```
Map<String, Listener> listeners= new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) {
        listeners.put("listener" + i, new Actionlistener());

}
```